# Java8 Bean Validation for Enum type using Hibernate

Tags: java, enums, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, javax

Here's my situation,

I have a class with `Enum` type fields. I want to execute annotated validation for `enum` types, similar to annotations for strings, example: `@Size`, `@NotNull` etc.

Problem is, `json` deserializer fails on `enum` type before validation occurs.

```
public class myClass {
    @JsonProperty
    //@SomeCustomValidator -- ??
    private EnumType enumValue;
}

public enum EnumType {
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

Few things:

1. I do not want to change the data type to `String`.
2. Tried steps in following threads, didn't fix my problem.

   [Tried this link, but get an error in deserialization before validation hits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445197/jsr-303-bean-validation-for-enum-fields)

   [Tried this link, but it works only when data Type is `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294587/java-string-validation-using-enum-values-and-annotation/6294691#6294691)

Comment: So if you only use `EnumType` in your class, what whould you want to validate? You want to validate your `EnumType enumValue` equals to a fixed enum or what?

Answer (score 0):

Validation works after the type of the argument is resolved. So I don't see a way how to use String validating annotations on enums. As workaround you can use @JsonCreator and do some validation before object creation.

```
public enum EnumType {
    A,
    B,
    C;

    @JsonCreator
    public static EnumType from(String s) {
        // add your logic here, for example
        /*
        if (Stream.of(values()).map(Enum::name).noneMatch(name -> name.equals(s))) {
            throw new MyServiceException("Bad value " + s);
        }
        */
        return valueOf(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good approach.., but no logic works unless I return null, in which case no exception occurs and a null value is assigned to field. Do you have a working solution with this approach?

Comment: You can throw an Exception or return null or any instance of your enum. I thought your goal was to throw custom Exception based on String value from json. If it wasn't I don't know what the goal you are trying to achieve.